# Azkaban flow parameters

Tags: java, azkaban

How do you set flow parameters for every job? I'm trying to configure a custom alerter and I want every job to trigger it. It look like it's looking for a "alert.type" property from the flow parameters, but right now I can only manage to trigger that through the interface. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST API:

`curl -k -d flowOverride[alert.type]=my-alerter -d scheduleDate=01/30/2017 -d scheduleTime=03,44,pm,PDT -d is_recurring=off -d projectId=1 -d ajax=scheduleFlow -d projectName=myproject -d flow=myflow -b "azkaban.browser.session.id=..." http://localhost:8081/schedule`

Please notice the parameter

`flowOverride[alert.type]=alerter-name`

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/azkaban-dev/pUYYpsmNsbk

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I modified the source code,
module: `azkaban-common`,
class: `azkaban.server.HttpRequestUtils`
after line number 104, add this code: `flowParamGroup.put("alert.type", "XXX");`

Comment: by the way, I use the version is 3.43.0